# change value of variable in r using dplyr

Tags: r

```
refine_original %>%
  + mutate(company=replace(company, grepl("ps",company), "phillips")) %>%                        
  + as.data.frame()

Error in replace(company, grepl("ps", company), "phillips") : 
  object 'company' not found
```

I do not why it is giving error object not found.

```
> str(refine_original)
'data.frame':   25 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ company              : Factor w/ 19 levels "ak zo","akz0",..: 10 8 7 13 11 9 3 4 5 2 ...
 $ Product.code...number: Factor w/ 23 levels "p-23","p-34",..: 4 3 19 20 17 1 13 11 22 2 ...
 $ address              : Factor w/ 25 levels "Delfzijlstraat 54",..: 9 10 11 12 13 14 19 20 21 22 ...
 $ city                 : Factor w/ 1 level "arnhem": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ country              : Factor w/ 1 level "the netherlands": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ name                 : Factor w/ 20 levels "dhr j. Gansen",..: 7 6 1 9 4 5 2 10 3 8 ...
```

Please help

Comment: Is there a reproducible refine_original dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has extra `+` signs in it. remove them then the errors should go away:

```
refine_original %>%
  mutate(company=replace(company, grepl("ps",company), "phillips")) %>%                        
  as.data.frame()
```